# Java.lang.OutOfMemory error while using substring function inside a loop

Tags: java, string

I am trying to remove all the substrings enclosed with in square braces in a given string. I am using a while loop to process the string until there are no square braces [ and ] in the string, and i am using the substring function inside the loop. Here is the code:

```
public String removeSquareBraceAndEnclosedSubstring(String inputString) {

     //continue until there is atleast one [ and one ]
     while (inputString.indexOf('[') > 0 && inputString.indexOf(']') > 0){

          int lastIndexOfOpenBrace = inputString.lastIndexOf('[');
          int firstIndexOfCloseBrace = inputString.indexOf(']');

          String beforeOpenBrace = inputString.substring(0, lastIndexOfOpenBrace);
          String afterCloseBrace = "";

          if (!inputString.endsWith("]"))
               afterCloseBrace = inputString.substring(firstIndexOfCloseBrace + 1
                                                                 , inputString.length());

          inputString = beforeOpenBrace + afterCloseBrace ;
      }
      return inputString;
}
```

I am getting an error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1913) on calling this method
```

I do not want to increase the heap size to solve this. I tried making use of functions like intern(), replacing string assignment by calling String constructor. Also i tried processing using a string builder instead of a string. Nothing seems to solve the issue. Is there a better solution or approach to solve this problem?

Comment: You created an infinite loop. The opening and closing braces can't both be on position 0.

Comment: @a123 Can you add the example string?

Comment: @RedSonja  The while condition is trying to check if there is a substring surrouded by [ and ]. So the condition checks if [ and ] exists. How is it infinite? it stops when there are no [ and ] in the string i.e when indexOf [ and indexOf ] returns -1 on no occurrence.

Comment: are you sure you are cutting out the bracket when you do this : `inputString.substring(firstIndexOfCloseBrace + 1` ? (i think you aren't. which means you never run out of `]` characters in your input string, and your loop never exits.
Also, there are more efficient ways of doing this.

Comment: @RedSonja i think this is indeed an infinite loop, but not for the reason you mentioned.

Comment: @DarshanMehta   example string: hi[hello[there]world]bye

Comment: @TimothyGroote can you please point out when it turns as an infinite loop?

Comment: @TimothyGroote The method does remove the [ and ] from the given input. I tested it for multiple inputs and it works. I run into the outOfMemory error when the method is repeatedly invoked my other methods.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind when diagnosing OutOfMemoryErrors is that the statement where the Exception happens must not be the culprit but can be just an innocent victim. So while the error might happen here there might as well be a memory leak somwhere else in your code.

Comment: What inputs are being given in the other methods?

Comment: @DCON all inputs are of the format: /"http://example.com/":detail[(fn:resolve-QName(@xsi:type, .) = fn:QName('http://example.com/svc/errors/', 'example'))]

Comment: see `piet.t`'s comment - you must check the Stack Trace to find where it starts repeating, indicating a possible infinite loop... often the last (top) entries are *random* (only one byte is needed to trigger OutOfMemoryException)

Answer (score 2):

```
    public class Example{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "hi [foo [bar] buzz] there [foo]";
        String str2 = "this is a [sample] string [with some substrings enclosed with in square braces] yeah!";
        System.out.println(removeSquareBraceAndEnclosedSubstring(str1));
        System.out.println(removeSquareBraceAndEnclosedSubstring(str2));
    } 

    public static String removeSquareBraceAndEnclosedSubstring(String inputString) {
        while(inputString.contains("[")){
          int openPos = inputString.indexOf('[');
          inputString = inputString.substring(0,openPos)+ inputString.substring(findClosingBrace(inputString.toCharArray(), openPos)+1);
        }
        return inputString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    }

    public static int findClosingBrace(char[] text, int openPos) {
        int closePos = openPos;
        int counter = 1;
        while (counter > 0) {
            char c = text[++closePos];
            if (c == '[') {
                counter++;
            }
            else if (c == ']') {
                counter--;
            }
        }
        return closePos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code breaks when you have brackets beside each other like this: (numbers are index position)

```
012345678
[hi][bye]
```

This happens because you're detecting `lastIndexOfOpenBrace` to be at index 4; which it is. Your code is designed to remove anything that's found between the `lastIndexOfOpenBrace` and the `firstIndexOfCloseBrace`. (Basically between index 3 and 4) In this case, there's nothing to remove, and you get stuck in an infinite loop. Placing this code at the start of your while loop will remove this error.

```
if(inputString.contains("][")){
    inputString = inputString.replace("][", "");
    continue;
}
```

There could be more errors. I am unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always break when inputstring have close braces before open braces.
you can write a condition
 close bracs index should be greater than open braces index.